# Python sqlite3 not updating some tables while others get updated

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, sqlite, flask

I am making a website with Python backend using `flask` and `sqlite3`. Most of my program is working, but I have a flask function that is called on a button click and executed in parallel with `ajax` request. It has 3 lines of sqlite updating 3 different table, but only the last one is making changes in the table. here is the function:

```
@app.route('/add_slot',methods=["POST","GET"])
def add_slot():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
    sem = request.json["sem"]
    sec = request.json["sec"]
    sub = request.json["sub"]
    teacher = request.json["teacher"]
    room_no = request.json["room_no"]
    time = int(request.json["time"])
    day = int(request.json["day"])

    cur = conn.execute("select assign_slot from teacher where teacher_name = '" + teacher + "'")
    slots = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    slots = slots[:(day-1)*10 + time-1] + "1" + slots[(day-1)*10 + time:]


    cur = conn.execute("select availability from room where room_no = " + room_no)
    avail = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    avail = avail[:(day-1)*10 + time-1] + "0" + avail[(day-1)*10 + time:]
    conn.execute("update room set availability = '" + avail + "' where room_no = " + room_no)
    conn.execute("update teacher set assign_slot = '" + slots + "' where teacher_name = '" + teacher + "'")
    conn.execute("update tt set subject_name = '" + sub + "', teacher_name = '" + teacher + "', room_no = " + room_no + " where semester = " + sem + " and section = '" + sec + "' and time_ = " + str(time) + " and day = " + str(day))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    return
```

And the JS code calling the function is:

```js
The last sql line is working, which updates the table tt, but others don't. I tried executing the sql statements independently on the powershell, putting the same values for the variables as passed when the function is called, and they work in the powershell. So, why are they not working in the program?
function send_data(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/add_slot' ,
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                data : {'sec':document.getElementById("sec").value,'sem':document.getElementById("sem").value,'sub':document.getElementById("sub").value,'day':document.getElementById("sel1").value,'time':document.getElementById("sel2").value,'teacher':document.getElementById("sel3").value,'room_no':document.getElementById("sel_r").value}
            });
            close_popup();
            initial_processing();
        }
```

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus but they are not. I cannot print them as it is in parallel, but on running the select statement directly into the powershell does return result

Comment: Sorry for the misdirect; I just reread the code, realize my mistake idea, and am about to delete the comment. If you can't print them, can you log them somehow/somewhere?